# State to open and close a Dialog in TypeScript in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I used a material -ui Dialog.
The dialog is not able to open and close repeatly for my lack of ability. 
After closing the dialog , it was no logener open again.
How Should I fix my code?
I am using React and Redux . function OpenPepsi is in Container. can is got from Promise object.

```
function MainPage(props: Material) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Link variant="h3" onClick={props.OpenPepsi}>
            OpenPepsiDialog
      </Link>
      <br />

      {props.can && (
          <PepsiDialog
            can ={props.can}
            isOpen={!!props.can}
          />
      )}



function PepsiDialog(props: {
  c: can;
  isOpen: boolean;
}) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(props.isOpen);
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
  return (
    <Dialog  open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
      <React.Fragment>{c}</React.Fragment>
      );
```

action

```
export const OPEN_PEPSI = () => async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  const can = await getPepsi(FOO);
  dispatch(OPEN_PEPSI_NOTIFY(can));
};
```

Comment: You never set the state `open` to `true`, but only to `false` or at least in your code listing it's not visible.

Answer (score 1):

This line leads to incorrect behavior

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(props.isOpen);
```

Seems that you're updating `props.isOpen` in parent and expect to update `open` inside dialog. But this will not work. Argument of `useState` is used to initialize state, but will not change it on subsequent calls of component (till it mounted). So to update `open` variable based on `props.isOpen` you should add `useEffect` like below

```
useEffect (() => setOpen(props.isOpen), [props.isOpen])
```

This way `open` will be updated based on `isOpen` change.

But this sinplified form has one drawback. Dialog will be reopened only when `can` in Redux change to `false` and then again to `true`. So maybe you want to propagate closed state back to Redux store. In such case connect `PepsiDialog` to Redux and use `can` directly from Redux (remove local `useState`). Or alternatively you can pass callback to `PepsiDialog` which will be called on close and parent `MainPage` will propagate closed state to Redux